# Writing to file in python finishes only when manually stopping the program

Tags: python

I have a simple program that writes to a file in a for loop (30k+ iterations). I noticed that the program is taking abnormally long to finish, after which I decided to kill it. The file it is writing to has 29900 lines created withing 30s and the remaining 100 are not written - the program doesn't exit and it takes hours to do so.

Once I killed it, it finished writing the remaining 100 or so lines.

```
f1 = open('parts.txt', "w")

for line in lines:
    category          = line[2]

    f1.write(category + '\n')

print('------- done -------')
f1.close()
```

Is there anything obvious that I am missing?

Comment: Error - you have unmatched " and ' and ) - so this is not your real code. Please fix and give us a correct [mre]. Thanks

Comment: It is not my real code, because the file parts.txt is too large to post here. Rerunning and reproducing the code here is not necessary - my usage of files may be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a with statement, this way the file is always closed independent of the exit status.

```py
with open('parts.txt', 'w') as fw:
    for line in lines:
        category = line[2]
        fw.write(category + '\n')

print('----- done ------')
```

Comment: The explicit `fw.close()` is not needed?

Comment: while a sound advice this answer is premature - the only error the OP code shows is `SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal` because it is not valid python.

Comment: @oneiros nope, this is called implicitly when the with block is exited.

Comment: @oneiros look up the [`with` statement context manager](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#with)

Comment: @Krrr - will do. Thank for the post - I am somewhat new to the language and this is a concept I need to understand.

Answer (score 0):

I spent a while trying to figure out why this was happening to me - it turns out it wasn't my Python code's fault at all for me: my IDE (PyCharm) doesn't seem to refresh (or at least often) the file tree whilst the program is running. However, the files were still generated, and looking at the file explorer/finder (or unfocusing/refocusing PyCharm), the files were generated.

I know this wasn't the answer for OP, but for anyone else who's having issues down the line (and searching around and comes across this) and nothing done in Python seems to work - check if the file has been generated with your system's file browser!